# javascript object array input to array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What i want to do: 3 html inputs, onclick (addCar) - constructor Cars creates object (based on inputs: name, time, speed and driver) and stores it in array "cars". onclick (race) - print all created objects (console.log) from array cars.

This is what i have so far:

```js
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var time = document.getElementById("time");
var speed = document.getElementById("speed");
var driver = document.getElementById("driver");
var addCar = document.getElementById("addCar");
var race = document.getElementById("race");
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var cars = [];

function Cars(name, time, speed, driver, distance){
    this.name = name;
    this.time = time;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.distance = 0;
}

addCar.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var carNew = new Cars (name.value, time.value, speed.value, driver.value);
    cars.push(carNew);
});

race.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log(cars);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>J21ND</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="J21ND.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fields">
            <h1>Car Race</h1>
            <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Input car name">
            <input id="time" type="text" placeholder="Input car time">
            <input id="speed" type="text" placeholder="Input car speed">
            <input id="driver" type="text" placeholder="Input driver level, select: Rookie, Advanced or Pro">
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button id="addCar">Add Car</button>
            <button id="Race">Start Race</button>
        </div>
        <div id="box">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `<button id="Race">Start Race</button>`. Here id is `Race`.

Which is not the same as `var race = document.getElementById("race");` Here id is `race`. And, `Race` != `race`

I made them equal and here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tanmayrajani/96ug5z5n/) that's logging `cars` on console!

Comment: but it only prints [cars], maybe im printing it wrong? For example, if i added 3 cars, when i print i want to see all of the object details like name time speed and driver.

Comment: @Benua I tried adding two different `cars` and it works fine for me in the same fiddle

Comment: @Benua [here](http://imgur.com/4PBIxgf)'s how the console looks after adding two cars

Comment: Yep, found it, now array print is ok. Thanks a lot! Rookie mistake.. However, when i print my code on chrome, the order of elements is messed up and name shows undefined. But i have the same code as you do. Any clue?

Comment: @Benua I can look at it if you post details (maybe in new question). Please accept and upvote this answer if you found helpful.